# Matplolib subplots what is the purpose of the fig and axs variables

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, subplot, fig

Consider the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(19680801)
data = np.random.randn(2, 100)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(5, 5))
axs[0, 0].hist(data[0])
axs[1, 0].scatter(data[0], data[1])
axs[0, 1].plot(data[0], data[1])
axs[1, 1].hist2d(data[0], data[1])

plt.show()
```

I am aware that in order to create subplots you ned to write the line:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(5, 5)
```

However my question is concerning the meaning of this line, as in what does it actually achieve by producing the variables fig and axs, and why later on we use ax[0,0] as opposed to fig[0,0]

Comment: One figure containing 4 axes?

Answer (score 2):

`fig` describes the figure as a whole, but the `axs` in this case refers to all the subplots within the figure. Since you defined 2 rows and 2 columns of subplots, you call each subplot with `axs[0,0]` for the top left and `axs[1,1]` for the bottom right subplot. In order to change the size of a subplot you have to change the size of the overall figure in which the subplots are embedded.

The difference is subtle, but multiple subplots or just one subplot can be found in a figure. So to plot a line you would do this on the subplot axes and not on the figure.